# Is it possible to more than one object description in Django?

Tags: django

In model class we can define th object description

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % ("ID:",  self.id, "Active:", self.is_active,  "Bilingual:", self.is_bilingual, "Description:" , self.description )
```

But sometimes I need different descriptions in different situations.
Is it possible to maintain more than one description formats for same object in Django?

Comment: How would you tell django which description to use when? You can just define your own methods and call them in the context you need. E.g. `def my_context_description(self): return u'%s' % (self.id)`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't rely on the `__str__` or `__unicode__` method for anything other than a basic representation. For anything more complicated, do it elsewhere - eg in the template or other code.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine it inside `__unicode__` like so:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    # If the description of the object is empty, for example:
    if self.description == "":
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % ("ID:",  self.id, "Active:", self.is_active,  "Bilingual:", self.is_bilingual )
    return u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % ("ID:",  self.id, "Active:", self.is_active,  "Bilingual:", self.is_bilingual, "Description:" , self.description )
```

Comment: So it will be driven by object itself and not by from where  I call it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.description == "":
            self._desc = u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % ("ID:",  self.id, "Active:", self.is_active,  "Bilingual:", self.is_bilingual )
        else:
            self._desc = u'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s ' % ("ID:",  self.id, "Active:", self.is_active,  "Bilingual:", self.is_bilingual, "Description:" , self.description )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self._desc
```